# Power Automate to copy rows between sheets in excel

Tags: excel, power-automate

I have been trying for days to write an office script to copy rows between sheets based on a value selected in a drop-down list, then delete said row. I have tried many iterations of code but as I’m new to scripts its been unsuccessful every time.

However I was wondering if I needed a script period and could the process be done using Power Automate? I was intending on using it to do the trigger event in any case had the script been successful

Thanks

When I wrote the script it was supposed to copy the row from master sheet paste in the complete sheet to the last row. Delete said row from master.All triggered by a value selected in drop down list.
The scripts had varying outputs but none as intended.

Comment: You need to show your work so we can help.

Comment: Hi Skin, the query was really about Power Automate. I will post what the current script code I've been struggling with, but just wondered if I PA can do this direct?

Comment: function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
 let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
 // Set range O7 on selectedSheet
 selectedSheet.getRange("O7").setValue("7: In Use");
 let completeProjects = workbook.getWorksheet("CompleteProjects");
 // Paste to range A69 on completeProjects from range A7:AG7 on selectedSheet
 completeProjects.getRange("A69").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A7:AG7"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
 // Delete range 7:7 on selectedSheet
 selectedSheet.getRange("7:7").delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);

Comment: Please don’t paste it as a comments, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: The standard connectors in PowerAutomate deals with tables, if you need to deal with non table related data, you use an Office Script.

Comment: Thanks for the response, you have confirmed what I suspected with PA.  I shall remember to edit the question in the future when adding new info.

Comment: Ok, but you know PA can work with Office Scripts don’t you?

Comment: Yes I do, just though may safe some time I currently have a PA question running about an issue I have with PA. Thanks again.